# AWS Printing DynamoDB Table Via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface

I'm trying to find the right command to use in the CLI to print the contents of a table within DynamoDB.

I've tried using the following command but it gives me a "parameter validation failed" error.

`

```
aws dynamodb get-item \
    --table-name Traffic \
    --key file://traffic.json \
    --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

`

The AWS website is giving me a 403 error, at the moment, so I can't search for the solution through the official site.

Comment: If you want to get every record in a table, you would use `aws dynamodb scan` https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html

Answer (score 1):

To get all items in a table, use a scan operation, not a get item operation. This basic scan operation works fine with the CLI:

aws dynamodb scan --table-name Work

[image]

You can find all valid options here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `Scan` API  to output how the table looks in DynamoDB JSON format.

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name test \
--output text
```

If you have a list of keys to fetch in your traffic.json file then you should use `batch-get-item`.

If it's a single item you need then please share the contents of traffic.json file.